# Python Multiprocessing Pool : Missing one process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code to preprocess large file of text. To accelerate the processing, I try to use multiple processes. Before launching the pool, I split my file into smaller data files, one destined to each process.

Each process take as input one data file, preprocess it and put the result into a "preprocessed" json file.

```
PROCESS_NB = 8

def task(task_data):
        input_file_path = "data/input/{}.tsv".format(task_data[0])
        output_file_path = "data/preprocessed_files/preprocessed_{}.json".format(task_data[0])

        with open(input_file_path, "r") as input_file:
            content = input_file.read()

        preprocessed_collection = preprocess(text_collection=content, stopwords=task_data[1].stopwords)

        with open(output_file_path, "w") as preprocessed_file:
            preprocessed_file.write(json.dumps(preprocessed_collection))

        input_file.close()
        preprocessed_file.close()

def run():
    config = Config()

    prepare_inputs_file()

    filename_list = []
    for i in range(1, PROCESS_NB):
        filename_list.append(["data_{}".format(str(i)), config])

    pool = Pool(processes=PROCESS_NB)
    pool.map(task, filename_list)
```

In results, I wan't to have 8 data files and 8 preprocessed files. But I wan't figure out why I have 8 data files but only 7 preprocessed files. It seems like the eighth process can't finish his job.

I tried to print when each process start and end, and also to catch possible exceptions. But  only 7 processes seems to run.

Comment: because, you're not initiating 8 processes in your for loop, do `range(1, PROCESS_NB+1)` or just  `range(PROCESS_NB)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks suspicious:

```py
 for i in range(1, PROCESS_NB):
        filename_list.append(["data_{}".format(str(i)), config])
```

`range()` [is exclusively bound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) with respect to the `stop`-value:

```
>>> list(range(1, 8))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

So your list contains only 7 values. Try `range(1, PROCESS_NB + 1)` or `range(PROCESS_NB)` (starting at 0) instead?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that range stop when i == 8.